# How to disable Teraterm macro dialog box

Tags: macros, ttl, teraterm

I am using Tera Term V4.92

I create a TTL script to lunch Tera Term and connect to the COM Port 10

```
;;
;; Connection via COM port
;; 
connect '/C=10'

;;
;; The timeout limit is 1 min.
;;
timeout = 60

;;
;; Pauses until one of the timeout occurs.
;; 
;; 
waitevent 1

;;
;; Closes Tera Term
;;
closett

;;
;; Quits the execution of the macro.
;;
;;end
```

My script run perfectly but I want to disable a window lunched with Tera Term at the same time Titled 'MACRO - SCRIPT.TTL'

[image]

Any help please

regards
AAG

Comment: Off topic, belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I believe that you wanted to either ***minimize*** or ***hide*** the Macro box. This can be easily done with the use of ***show*** command.

```
;;
;; Connection via COM port
;; 
connect '/C=10'
show -1

;;
;; The timeout limit is 1 min.
;;
timeout = 60

;;
;; Pauses until one of the timeout occurs.
;; 
;; 
waitevent 1

;;
;; Closes Tera Term
;;
closett

;;
;; Quits the execution of the macro.
;;
;;end
```

You may refer here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/show.html

Hope that this answers you. Have a nice day.

Comment: thank you so much! It seems the right option. I will try it out and let you know about the result